# Uploading docx corrupts file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the code below to upload a file.  The files upload without error, but when I open a file with a .docx extension M$ says that the file is corrupted.  It is able to repair the file and then open, however.  I'd like to fix this so the document opens correctly.

```
string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[0].FileName).ToLower();
string fileName = @"C:\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + strExtension;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];

    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

EDITED:

File saves correctly with this code:

```
while ((bytesRead = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
```

Also saves correctly with `context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are reading the [HttpRequest.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx).  The better thing to do is check the [HttpRequest.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) collection.

(Or even easier, use a [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) server control).

Your code is copying the raw input, which is most likely multi-part, to a file.

Comment: When I switch to Files[0].InputStream, the file saves and opens correctly.

Comment: Yep and it's not only a 'better' thing to do, it's the correct one. There is a difference between the (raw) Http Input stream (which contains among other things the http payload) and the (multipart) transmitted files that are just one part of the whole input stream. You can certainly take that raw input stream and parse/extract that yourself (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1867) but as dana mentioned, the .Files property on the request does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but you could use [HttpPostedFile.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx) to save the content to the desired path.

```
string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[0].FileName).ToLower();
string fileName = @"C:\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + strExtension;
context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(fileName); // i'll ignore the violation of the law of demeter ;)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why I should use SaveAs over saving it with a stream?

Comment: if what you need done is already written, tested, and working for you, no reason to reinvent the wheel. that's how simple mistakes like this get introduced into your app.

Comment: I agree and I will remove the stream logic.  Thanks.